# Border on inside of LinearLayout on left side

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

How can I add a border on the inside of the following LinearLayout on the left side, such that it's `5dp` wide and fits the entire height of the LinearLayout? The height of the LinearLayout is dynamic, meaning that sometimes it can be `50dp` high and other times `60dp` high, etc.

Here is my current layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok fine. I didn't understand before.

So to do that create an xml file in the drawable folder with the following content. Name the xml 
"layout_mainBG"

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">      
    <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@android:color/background_dark" />
    <solid android:color="#800000c0"/> </shape>
```

This suits your needs.

If you want something more complex

And in your layout_main xml file under the `<LinearLayout>`  tag add this

```
android:baground = "@drawable/layout_mainBG
```

Refer to this site for more info. Even if it is dialog fragment it's just the same.

[Create background of Popup Window with custom shape](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/01/creat-background-of-popup-window-with.htmlhttp://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/01/creat-background-of-popup-window-with.html?m=1)

If you want one side only change the layout_mainBG 
To

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/bg" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This gives you a black border.

Comment: A border, not margin/padding. I'm looking to add a coloured border on the left side of the LinearLayout (like a rectangle).

Comment: @user just change for ex: the android:color = "#000000" if you want pure black or the solid 's android:color = "@color/bg"

Comment: This code gives you all four side border. Actual requirement is only left side border.

Comment: Oh sorry. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @Bhavin Shah now could you please remove the down vote?

Comment: It made the entire LinearLayout black.

Comment: What is the color of bg mentioned in @color/bg?

Comment: Nevermind, you almost have it right. It made the border color `@color/bg` and the background of the LinearLayout black (which is opposite to how I want it). Is there a reason it's making them opposite colors?

Comment: Ok sorry for the typo. I'll correct it. And no there is no reason for making it opposite.